# Bash - Optional argument with spaces

Tags: bash, shell, command-line-arguments

I have a bash script and I want to use it to pass an optional parameter with spaces to another script.
My script (pass_optional_arg.sh) looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

mandatory_arg=${1}

if [[ -z ${mandatory_arg} ]]
then
  echo "Mandatory arg missing"
  exit 1
fi

optional_arg=${2}

./echo_args.sh ${mandatory_arg} an_irrelevant_arg  "${optional_arg}"
```

Script echo_args.sh just prints the arguments in single quotes, as well as their number:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "Number of args: ${#}"
for var in "${@}"
do
    echo "Arg: '"${var}"'"
done
```

Output of running `./pass_optional_arg.sh a_mandatory_arg 'an arg with spaces'`

> Number of args: 3
>
> Arg: 'a_mandatory_arg'
>
> Arg: 'an_irrelevant_arg'
>
> Arg: 'an arg with spaces'

Which is exactly what I want.
However, if I run without providing the optional argument:
`./pass_optional_arg.sh a_mandatory_arg`

> Number of args: 3
>
> Arg: 'a_mandatory_arg'
>
> Arg: 'an_irrelevant_arg'
>
> Arg: ''

In this case I want the arguments to be 2, and not an empty arg at the end.

If I change the last line of pass_optional_arg.sh to remove the quotes from the optional arg `./echo_args.sh ${mandatory_arg} an_irrelevant_arg  ${optional_arg}`

then the second case is fixed but the first breaks:
`./pass_optional_arg.sh a_mandatory_arg 'an arg with spaces'`

> Number of args: 6
>
> Arg: 'a_mandatory_arg'
>
> Arg: 'an_irrelevant_arg'
>
> Arg: 'an'
>
> Arg: 'arg'
>
> Arg: 'with'
>
> Arg: 'spaces'

Of course, I could satisfy both cases with an if statement

```
if [[ -z ${optional_arg} ]]
then
  ./echo_args.sh ${mandatory_arg} an_irrelevant_arg
else
  ./echo_args.sh ${mandatory_arg} an_irrelevant_arg  "${optional_arg}"
fi
```

This may be fine for a small command like this, but cannot scale for several optional arguments. Also for a command that is very complicated and long, having to duplicate it like this is not ideal. Any way to make this work without the above if statement?

I found several questions about optional parameters OR parameters with spaces, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30086566/how-can-i-pass-optional-parameters-to-another-command-within-a-bash-script), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983048/passing-a-string-with-spaces-as-a-function-argument-in-bash) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17094086/passing-arguments-with-spaces-between-bash-script), but I could not find what I am asking for in any of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a conditional somewhere, because `"..."` is always going to be a distinct argument, even if the `...` is empty. By the way, you absolutely want to quote *all* the parameter expansions:

```
./echo_args.sh "${mandatory_arg}" an_irrelevant_arg "${optional_arg}"
```

You might want to use an array instead:

```
mandatory_arg=${1}

# Check $# directly; just because $1 is empty doesn't mean it is *missing*
if (( $# < 1 ))
then
  echo "Mandatory arg missing"
  exit 1
fi
# Or simply
# mandatory_arg=${1:?Mandatory arg missing}

args=( "$mandatory_arg" an_irrelevant_arg )
(( $# >= 2 )) && args+=("$2")

./echo_args.sh "${args[@]}"
```

Comment: Great solution!